# Elusive "Error 400" in Excel VBA macro - unable to understand cause

Tags: excel, vba

I have been bashing my head against an Error 400 that my VBA macro is throwing up seemingly at random, and I could really use some help.

Info collected so far:

- The macro run flawlessly from the VBA editor, either by steeping into it, by running it with breakpoints or by just executing it in its entirety.
- When launched from a button it seems to have a random (I would estimate 50%) chance of popping up with error 400
- Same random error chance happens if the macro is launched from "Macros > View Macro > Run"
- The errors do not follow any obvious pattern (Like OK > error > Ok > error), sometimes the macro executes correctly 5 times in a row, sometimes I get good runs alternated by errors, sometimes several tries in a row turn up with errors
- When an error happens, it appears that none of the macro has been executed (for example, if I manually unprotected a sheet, it stays unprotected after a failed attempt)

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "abc123"
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cyclades Data").Unprotect "abc123"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cyclades Data").Activate
  ThisWorkbook.Connections("Cyclades").Refresh
      DoEvents
  Calculate
      DoEvents
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cyclades Data").Protect Password:="abc123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shifts labour entry").Protect Password:="abc123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Meeting Sheet").Unprotect "abc123"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Meeting Sheet").Activate
  ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Refresh
      DoEvents
  Calculate
      DoEvents
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Meeting Sheet").Protect Password:="abc123", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True

  ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Cyclades").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
      DoEvents
  ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Shifts").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
      DoEvents
  Calculate
      DoEvents

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Utilization").Unprotect "abc123"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Utilization").Activate
  ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Utilization(1)").Refresh
      DoEvents
  Calculate
      DoEvents
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Utilization").Protect Password:="abc123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot chart data").Protect Password:="abc123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Meeting Sheet").Activate
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ThisWorkbook.Protect "abc123"
  ```

Important notes:
Office 365 - Excel version 1907
All connections have "enable background refresh" unchecked.

Expected result:
Everything is refreshed in the correct order and everything is protected after the execution

Comment: What's the error *message*? No one memorizes the numbers... And what line of code causes it?

Comment: The error message is simply "Error 400". I am unable to narrow down what line of code generates it as the error does not happen when the macro is executed from the VBA editor (neither by stepping into it, by running it with breakpoints or by just executing it in its entirety).

Comment: Put some `Debug.Print` lines in the code every few lines to narrow it down.

Comment: Doesn't Debug.Print send stuff to the immediate window? The macro runs without any problem from the VBA editor.

Comment: I added an "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler", with an handler consisting of "MsgBox Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number & " - " & Erl". Weirdly enough the goto works fine if I intentionally introduce an error in the code (to catch THAT error at least), but the error 400 is not affected in any way.

Comment: Debug.Print prints to the Immediate Window, but it will do that even if the VBA Editor is behind the Excel window while the code is running. It doesn't change the focus at all. In some search "hits" I found the suggestion was to use "On Error Resume Next", but you don't want that for the entire code, so locating the lines or block would be important.

Comment: So, apparently the error pops up before the first line of code is executed. after "Sub refresh()" and two line of comments, I added a Debug.Print "1". this is not recorded when the execution fails with error 400

Comment: What is calling `sub refresh()`? If you put `On Error Resume Next` before the first line of code and `On Error GoTo 0` (or some other error handler label` after the first line of code, does that help?

Comment: `sub refresh()` is the codeblock posted above.    
Even with `On Error Resume Next` the issues still occurs at random.